# access each group in spark keyvaluegroupeddataset

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Spark and I have a specific question about how to use spark to address my problem, which may be simple.

**Promblem:**

I have a model, which predicts the sales of products. Each product also belongs to a category like shoes, clothes etc. And we also have actual sales data. So the data look like this:

```
+------------+----------+-----------------+--------------+
| product_id | category | predicted_sales | actual_sales |
+------------+----------+-----------------+--------------+
|    pid1    |   shoes  |      100.0      |     123      |
|    pid2    |   hat    |      232        |     332      |
|    pid3    |   hat    |      202        |     432      |
+------------+----------+-----------------+--------------+
```

product_id  category  predicted_sales  actual_sales

What I'd like to do is: I want to calculate the number(or percentage) of intersection between top 5% products ranked by actual_sales and top 5% products ranked by predicted_sales for each category.

Doing this for the whole products instead of for each category would be easy, something like below:

```
def getIntersectionRatio(df:dataframe, per :Int): Double = {
      val limit_num = (df.count() * per / 100.0).toInt
      var intersection = df.orderBy("actual_sales").limit(limit_num)
          .join(df.orderBy("predicted_sales").limit(limit_num), Seq("product_id"), "inner")
      intersection.count() * 100.0 / limit_num
}
```

However, I need to calculate the intersection for each category. The result will be something like this

```
+-----------+------------------------+
|  Category | intersection_percentage|
+-----------+------------------------+
```

**My ideas**

1. User Defined Aggreation Fuction or Aggregators
   I think I can achieve my goal if I use groupBy or GroupByKey with UDAF or Aggregators but they are too inefficient because they take 1 row each time and I will have to store each row in the buffer inside UDAF or Aggregator.

```
df.groupby("category").agg(myUdaf)

class myUdaf extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {
//Save all the rows to an arraybuffer
//and then transform the buffer back to df
//And then we the the same thing as we did for whole product in  getIntersectionRatio defined previously
}
```

2. Self implemented partitioning
   I can select the distinct categories and the use map to process each category, in which I join the element with df to get the partition

```
df.select("category").distinct.map(myfun(df))

def myfun(df: dataframe)(row : Row):Row = {
  val dfRow = row.toDF //not supported but feasible with other apis
  val group = df.join(broadcast(dfRow), seq(category), inner)
  getIntersectionRatio(group)
}
```

Do we have a better solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Regarding whats in the title - you have access to every group through any of the map-, flatmap-, reduceGroups methods provided by KeyValueGroupedDataset https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/KeyValueGroupedDataset.html. Not sure about the rest of your question.

Comment: Thanks. My bad, yep, it's a bit confusing. I've taken a look at the map, flatmap, reduceGroup, they all seems to access the records one by one, not sure if they can help in my case.